# Exclude some samplers in JMeter html dashboard report in non gui mode

Tags: html, jmeter, command-line-interface, report, performance-testing

I have two http request samplers inside a Thread Group.

I would like to ignore the first sampler when I run the tests in non GUI mode (cli).

The main reason is to ignore the first sampler in the generated HTML report.

I still need the Sampler 1 to run under the hood even if I filter when running it in cli mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send in non GUI extra parameter/JMeter property as `-JignoreFirstSampler`

Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the first Sampler with code to ignore sampler in results:

```
    if (props.get("ignoreFirstSampler") != null) {
        prev.setIgnore()
    }
```

Sampler 1 will still executed, but won't be shown in report

Comment: bof answers are working. I check the last one which is more simpler and suitable for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your HTTP Request samplers under the [Transaction Controllers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/)

   [image]
2. Click `Tools -> Export transactions for report`

   [image]
3. Amend generated `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property  value and remove "unwanted" transactions
4. Run JMeter in non-GUI mode and provide this `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property via `-J` command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter="^(Sampler 2)(-success|-failure)?$" -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
   ```
5. That's it, HTML Reporting Dashboard will contain only `Sampler 2` transaction results

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Reporting configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)

Comment: Thanks you very much @Dmitri. With your suggestion, The sampler 1 will still run under the hood? I need the sampler 1 to still run before Sampler 2 even if I filter in the run command.